# How to Share mp3 file in chat in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a bot in discord.py and want it to send a mp3 file which is saved on my pc. I have no clue how to do it. I am coding in repl.it

Comment: I am pretty sure you can just send the file. `await channel.send(file=discord.File('your_file.mp3'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All types of files can be sent with `discord.File` through a message. In your command, just sending an MP3 file can be sent with,

```
await ctx.send(file=discord.File(file, "result.mp3"))
```

A full and detailed reference can be found here:

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=file#discord.File